# Proving acceleration is spacelike in a general spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration

I would like to convince myself that acceleration $a^{\mu}=v^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}v^{\mu}$ of a massive particle following a trajectory $x^{\mu}(\tau)$ in some general spacetime  is spacelike, i.e. $a^{\mu}a_{\mu}$>0;

Here I use the notation $\nabla_{\mu}$ to denote a covariant derivative and $v^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}$ to denote four-velocity.

It is trivial to show $v^{\mu}v_{\mu}=-1$ (hence timelike);

It is fairly straightforward to show that $a^{\mu}v_{\mu}=0$, i.e. they are orthogonal.

However, my attempts to go further than that were unsuccessful and I would appreciate some hints or help.

Comment: You've already proved it haven't you? Just take the rest frame of the particle. In that frame the four velocity is $(v_t, 0, 0, 0)$ so the four acceleration must have the form $(0,  a_x, a_y, a_z)$. And if the four-aceleration is spacelike in any frame it must be spacelike in all frames.

Comment: Hmm. Alright. Hadn't thought of that. So if any vector has its $a^0$ component as 0, you can immediately deduce it to be spacelike?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$